# using ahk to close a pop up dialogue within visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, autohotkey

I've remapped a few keys, which has been working fine; however, I'm having a difficult time trying to get rid of a pop up dialogue within visual studio:

[image]

Here's what I have tried:

```
WinWaitActive, Microsoft Visual Studio
If WinActive("Microsoft Visual Studio")
{
  WinGetText, HayStack
  Needle = "A network-related or instance-specific error"
  IfInString, Haystack, %Needle%
  {
      MsgBox, The string was found.
      return
  }
  else
      Sleep, 1
}
return
```

However, I get no response whatsoever.

The entire script including a few key remappings is below:

```
SetTitleMatchMode 2
!z::Send, !{F4}
!x::Send, !fc
!c::Send, 23481241240910324
^d::Send {End}{Shift Down}{Up}{End}{Shift Up}{Backspace}
!a::
If WinActive("Microsoft Visual Studio")
{

}
else
{
  Send !{F4}n
}
return
WinWaitActive, Microsoft Visual Studio
If WinActive("Microsoft Visual Studio")
{
  WinGetText, HayStack
  Needle = "A network-related or instance-specific error"
  IfInString, Haystack, %Needle%
  {
      MsgBox, The string was found.
      return
  }
  else
      Sleep, 1
}
return
```

**What am I doing wrong? How do I get rid of this dialogue?**

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Why can't you simply click OK and fix the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure to get the window title and text using the window spy utility from your autohotkey install folder.
There are several ways to close a window, sometimes you have to be a bit more forcefully. It's even possible that you need to run your script with admin privileges. You also don't need to define a hotkey which has to be pressed to get rid of the window. You can completely automate the whole process. Give this a try:

```
#Persistent ;Ensure the script doesn't exit immediately
If not A_IsAdmin ;force the script to run as admin
{
    Run *RunAs "%A_ScriptFullPath%"
    ExitApp
}

;Enter the correct win title and a correct substring of the win text and maybe also the ClassNN of the button whoch closes it
windowTitle = Microsoft Visual Studio
windowText = A network-related or instance-specific error
closeButton = Button1

;Call CloseWindow periodically passing the contents of above variables as arguments:
CloseWindowWithBoundArgument := Func("CloseWindow").bind(windowTitle, windowText, closeButton)
SetTimer, %CloseWindowWithBoundArgument%

;Wait for a window to exist, then close it:
CloseWindow(winTitle,winText,buttonClassNN) {
    WinWait, %winTitle%, %winText% ;wait until the window exists
    ;There are multiple methods to close a window:

    ;Close window method 1 (similar to pressing alt+F4)
    PostMessage, 0x112, 0xF060,,, %winTitle%, %winText%

    ;Close window method 2 (sends a WM_CLOSE message; somewhat forcefully)
    WinClose, %winTitle%, %winText%

    ;Close window method 3 (forcefully closing a window using server different methods internally)
    WinKill, %winTitle%, %winText%

    ;Close window method 4 (clicking a button to close the window)
    ControlClick, %buttonClassNN%, %winTitle%, %winText%
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> **What am I doing wrong?**

- `Needle = "A network-related or instance-specific error"` - String assignments don't work like that in AHK. You either use `Needle := "A network..."` or `Needle = A network...`.
- What's the point of your <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>-Hotkey? If the window pops up, why don't you simply press <kbd>Enter</kbd>??
- ```
  If WinActive("Microsoft Visual Studio")
   {

   }
   else
   {
     Send !{F4}n
   }
  ```

  So, close the window when the popup is **not** active??
- `return`

  Everything after this keyword doesn't get executed. Your script will *never* reach `WinWaitActive, Microsoft Visual Studio`.

btw cool name bro

Comment: thanks! here's what i've got so far, http://pastebin.com/9pASqZEh , i've wrapped it in A loop, but it doesnt seem to be responding at all. what are your thoughts? i very much appreciate your help! have a great week

Comment: you don't need `if winactive()` right after `winwaitactive`, because the latter implies the former

Comment: @PleaseStopUpvotingMe i still dont understand the meaning of `Send !{F4}n` but - the code looks okay to me, wouldn't know what isn't working with it. cheers

Comment: you should place `msgbox`es inside your code and find out what happens and what exactly doesn't work.