# How to close/minimize/maximize or send keys to window or popup with Autohotkey?

Tags: window, autohotkey, minimize, maximize

How to use Autohotkey to automatically close, minimize, maximize or send keys to a window as soon as it pops up? I can detect a dialog and close it with this:

```
WinWaitActive, TITLE
WinClose, TITLE
```

But this doesn't work if the window isn't open on script execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very common task AHK is used for.

First you need the title of the window you want to address. Read [How to get the title of a window with AHK?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35071473/4579407).

## The code

For the basic functionalitiy of closing a window we need [Loop](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Loop.htm), [WinWaitActive](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinWaitActive.htm) and [WinClose](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinClose.htm).

*Example for a Firefox window with Stack Overflow open.*

```
Loop {
  WinWaitActive, Stack Overflow - Mozilla Firefox
  WinClose,
}
```

### Explanation

The `Loop` repeats the process to close the window multiple times. `WinWaitActive` waits until the the window gets activated (pops up) and `WinClose` closes it.

*Hint: If you don't specify a specifiy window title like with `WindowClose` the last found window, which is the one from `WinWaitActive` is used.*

**minimize/maximize**

Instead of `WinClose` use [WinMaximize](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinMaximize.htm) or [WinMinimize](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinMinimize.htm) to perform the corresponding action.

**Sending Keys**

If you want to send specific keys (e.g. <kbd>Enter</kbd>) to the window use [Send](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm)

```
Loop {
  WinWaitActive, Stack Overflow - Mozilla Firefox
  send {Enter}
}
```

---

### Additions

If the basic version does not work or you want to create an more advanced script, here are some possible modifications.

**More Force**

If `WinClose` does not work try [WinKill](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinKill.htm) or `Send, !{F4}` to use more force.

**As Admin**

Admin rights might be necessary to close the window, use this code snippet on top of your script to make sure it runs with full access.

```
If not A_IsAdmin ;force the script to run as admin
{
    Run *RunAs "%A_ScriptFullPath%"
    ExitApp
}
```

**Other matching methods**

On default the window title has to be an **exact match**. To change this behavior and allow *partial* or *start with* matches use [SetTitleMatchMode](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTitleMatchMode.htm) on top of your script, e.g. `SetTitlematchMode, 2` for partial match.

Instead of title, the window class (ahk_class) or .exe (ahk_exe) from Window Spy can be used.

```
WinWaitActive, ahk_class MozillaWindowClass
```

or
    WinWaitActive, ahk_exe firefox.exe

Select the one which suits your needs carefully to only react to the correct window.

Comment: Really good idea! I have some suggestions for improvement. Let's use SetTimer instead of Loop, because Loop blocks the script from doing anything else. There are more ways to close a window and there is better way than sending Alt+F4. To close certain windows, admin rights are required. See my answer from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34480195/using-ahk-to-close-a-pop-up-dialogue-within-visual-studio/34493278#34493278

Comment: @Forivin thanks, i will insert your ideas to the additions part to expand it even further. I just want to keep a very basic version for all those guys completly new to AHK. As you are an active member of the AHK tag and answered questions like this, i invite you to edit and improve my anser on your own.

Comment: 3 ways to open Window Spy right in the beginning seems overkill, don't you think? Also, it would be better to use WinWait instead of WinWaitActive. And `PostMessage, 0x112, 0xF060,,, %winTitle%` does the same thing as Alt+F4, but it's more reliable as it doesn't require the window to be active.

Comment: I think it might be a better idea to create a new question that just says "How to find a Window Title or Text" for the Windo Spy tutorial and then link to it from other questions.