# How to determine title and additional infos from an open window for use with Autohotkey?

Tags: windows, autohotkey, titlebar

To access and control a window, dialog or popup with Autohotkey the title of that specific window is needed. For some windows the title can be read directly if its visible, but some windows hide it. The window class and the exe (ahk_class and ahk_exe) aren't visible at all. How to gather this information reliable?

Answer (score 2):

Use the **Window Spy** tool, which is installed together with AHK, it can be started various ways:

- Right click the **tray icon** of a running AHK script and select `Window Spy`
- Start the `AU3_Spy.exe` in the **AHK installation folder**
- Use the **Windows search** to search for `Window Spy`

You will get a window called `Active Window Info` with various infos about your current active (topmost) window. The first box is the one you need.

**Example**

[image: Window Spy example]

The box gives title, class and .exe to detect the target window of which every line can be used to identify the window. Now you should activate the window you want to address and copy the information.

*Hint: You can (un-)freeze the display with <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>*