# AHK: Automation of dialog boxes

Tags: autohotkey, hotkeys

How to automate the dialog boxes, sometimes the dialog boxes appear multiple times, If dialog box is appear automatically press ok or enter. 
Is there a way to Automation of dialog boxes, using AHK scripts?

I used the following script

```
while WinActive("Convert Properties")
{
Send, {ENTER}
sleep 600
}
```

Comment: This question has been asked and answered multiple times, try the search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to get the window title using the window spy utility from your autohotkey install folder.

```
windowTitle = Convert Properties

;Call CloseWindow periodically passing the windowTitle as argument:
CloseWindowWithBoundArgument := Func("CloseWindow").bind(windowTitle)
SetTimer, %CloseWindowWithBoundArgument%

;Wait for a window to exist, then close it:
CloseWindow(winTitle) {
    WinWait, %winTitle%, %winText%   ; wait until the window exists
    WinClose, %winTitle%, %winText%  ; close it
}
```

[For a more detailed answer click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34480195/using-ahk-to-close-a-pop-up-dialogue-within-visual-studio/34493278#34493278).